# Set value of a property after constructor without calling additional method

Tags: c#

```
public class Button {
    private Tuple<int, int> _transformed;

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Button() {
        _transformed = Util.Transform(X, Y, Align.Center);
    }

    public void Display() {
        // Example methods to display button's elements
        // DrawBorder(_transformed ...)
        // DrawBackground(_transformed ...)
        // DrawButtonText(_transformed ...)
    }
}

public class GUI {
    private Button _button;

    public GUI() {
        _button = new Button( ) {
            X = 64,
            Y = 64
        };
    }

    public void DisplayGUI() {
        _button.Display( );
    }
}
```

Let's assume that we've got a static method `Transform` that transforms `X` and `Y` according to the given alignment, eg. `Align.Center`. We'll keep the result inside a `_transformed` field.

#### Problem

**In short:** I want to set the value of a field/property with a result of the external method that uses values of other properties inside the same class, automatically after creation of an instance, without calling additional methods or workarounds

My goal is to create generic `Button` class in which you can assign multiple properties (like in CSS - position, text-align, color, background, etc.) to define style of the button. Properties are set during creation of the `Button` instance and are changed occasionally (eg. position is changed on window size change by the user). Let's focus on the position. After window change, position should be reinitialized using `Transform` method.

- There will be quite few properties to control style of the `Button`. Not all of them have to be used, so they shouldn't be passed as the constructor's parameters.
- `Transform` method cannot be set inside `Display` method due to
  its repeat cycle - it's invoked every frame (target is 16.6ms), not an optimal solution.

Main problem with the current solution is that it doesn't work. If I set value of `_transformed` in the constructor then properties don't have values set, so it looks like `_transformed = Util.Transform(0, 0, Align.Center)` all the time.

#### Solutions

**1. Simplest solution would be to add method that are invoked after initialization and on window size change:**

```
public void Init() {
    _transformed = Util.Transform(X, Y, Align.Center);
}
```

but it is not a good option in my opinion, due to given examples of usage:

```
public GUI() {
    _button = new Button( ) { X = 64, Y = 64 }
    _button.Init();
    _button2 = new Button( ) { X = 128, Y = 256 }
    _button2.Init();
    // ...
}
// Or...
public GUI() {
    (_button = new Button( ) { X = 64, Y = 64 }).Init();
    (_button2 = new Button( ) { X = 64, Y = 64 }).Init();
    (_button3 = new Button( ) { X = 64, Y = 64 }).Init();
    // ...
}
```

**2. I can move invoke of the `Transform` method to the property, but it's still invoking `Transform` method each frame**

```
private Tuple<int, int> Transformed { get { return Util.Transform(X, Y, Align.Center); } }

public void Display() {
    // DrawButtonText(Transformed ...)
    // DrawBorder(Transformed ...)
    // DrawBackground(Transformed ...)
}
```

I think that the best solution is just to let it invoke `Transform` in the `Display` method, but I'm curious if there is a better, more optimal way to implement it as I described without continuously overwriting the field with the same value.

---

#### Answer

Thank you all for your answers. In my opinion the best solution is by @Alexander Petrov with lazy loading. I think it's the most elegant way to implement as it requires a little of code, match all requirements and it's optimal. I modified it slightly adding `_source`, because I want to avoid calling multiple times `Value`. Changed `_transformed.Value.Item1` to `Transformed.Item1`.

```
public class Button {
    private Lazy<Tuple<int, int>> _source;
    private Tuple<int, int> Transformed { get { return _source.Value; } }

    public Button() {
        _source = new Lazy<Tuple<int, int>>(() => Util.Transform(X, Y, Align.Center));
    }

    public void Display() {
        // Example methods to display button's elements
        // DrawBorder(Transformed ...)
        // DrawBackground(Transformed ...)
        // DrawButtonText(Transformed ...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the values for the properties into the constructor?

Comment: Can the value of X or Y change after initialization? If so, should the value of `_transformed` then be recalculated?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Let's say you've got 20 properties, so you need 20 arguments in the constructor, because sometimes you need 5 and sometimes 18 properties to be set. 

You can set all arguments to optional, but then you've got something like (null, null, null, null, value, null, null, value ...)

Comment: @devNull they can and _transfomed should be then recalculated, but it varies - sometimes button won't change values at all (user won't resize window) and sometimes it will a lot (user want to be pixel perfect with his window resize)

Comment: If in some cases you need 2 properties and 10 in other, create a class that you pass in as argument. Give the class a meaningful name such as `FancyButtonProperties`, `BasicButtonProperties` and so on. Also, look into the builder pattern as that may be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lazy initialization.

```
public class Button
{
    private Lazy<Tuple<int, int>> _transformed;

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Button()
    {
        _transformed = new Lazy<Tuple<int, int>>(() => Util.Transform(X, Y));
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_transformed.Value);
    }
}
```

The first time calls `Value` happens, the tuple is created.

```
var button = new Button() { X = 64, Y = 64 };
button.Display(); // output (64, 64)
```

Comment: It's fine for one `_transformed` property. Things get worse if we've got more of them like `_buttonTransformed`, `_textTransformed`, `_borderTransformed` etc. because we get more of `bool init` for each "Transformed" property. It's fine, because we do it once, but it's a lot of lines of code for that simple problem. I guess it's very complicated to make it both generic and optimal at the same time in comparison to simple set it in `Display()` method and lose a little bit of processing power :/

Comment: Thank you, I think it's the best solution to this problem so far. Edited post with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Three options I can think of:

1. call the `Init` method inside the setter of each property ie: (apologies for formatting, on mobile and can’t get it to format)

```
private int _X;     
public int X 
{  
    get { return _X; }.  
    set  
    {   
        _X = value;   
        Init();   
    }   
}
```

2. your option 2 but cache/memoize the result so it’s not recomputed unless the inputs change.
3. specify all parameters in the constructor but call with named arguments to avoid multiple nulls for non specified values (and clarity):

```
public class Button
{
    int x, y, width, height;
    public Button(int x = 0, int y = 0, int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
       this.x = x;
       // etc
       Init();
    }
    
    void Init()
    {   
    }
}

public class Main
{
    Button b = new Button(x:20, y:30);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution is quite tricky. It requires that all arguments have to be set, let's say `Transform` need 5 properties as args `Transform(Align, X, Y, Width, Height)`, then all of them has to be set, otherwise they will have default values. Second thing is that if all of these 5 properties has an `Init()` in set then `Init()` will be invoked 5 times. We can move `Init()` to the last property used, but then we need to remember about order (in this example `Height` should be set as last), +it's not generic solution

Comment: As I understand some or all of the properties are optional. If you therefore provide default values, I don't think it matters so much that Init is called every time. Otherwise you have no way of telling that the last parameter has been set, unless you make an explicit call. Given this, is it actually that bad that Init is called 5 (and only 5) times?

Comment: Added third option